# How to fix this index.tsx:25 No routes matched location "/Reel/src/App"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

How to fix this index.tsx:25 No routes matched location "/Reel/src/App" i want that when a user click on the image than reels start playing so when i add  but now the error is coming in console index.tsx:25 No routes matched location "/Reel/src/App"  how to fix that inside my social media app project i have one reels project means their are two projects pls tell the image pls tell how to fix this at least try to fix this problem.. [image: code image] [image: error image]

```
import { Header } from "../../features/theme/Header";
import styles from "./Home.module.css";
import { useAppSelector } from "../../app/hooks";
import { Feed } from "../../features";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import './Reel/src/App'



export function Home(): JSX.Element {
  const { currentUserImage } = useAppSelector((state) => state.currentUser);

  return (
    <div className={styles.home}>
      <Header page="Home" />
      <div className={styles.tweetField}>
        <div className={styles.userAvatar}>
          <img src={currentUserImage} alt="" />
          <h1>Mowe</h1>
        </div>
        <Link to="/Reel/src/App">
        <div className={styles.userAvatar}>
          <img src={currentUserImage} alt=""/>
          <h1>Haewae</h1>
        </div>
        </Link>
        <div className={styles.userAvatar}>
          <img src={currentUserImage} alt="" />
          <h1>‎ ‎ ‎  Lveewe</h1>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.userAvatar}>
       <img src={currentUserImage} alt=""/>
          <h1>gy</h1>
        </div>
        <div>

          <div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Feed />
    </div>
  );

}
```

Comment: You specified the URL to a `Link` but how did you define your routes? Like `<Router>` or `<Route>` tags?

Comment: @mc-user i dont know that what do to now i am still learning react

Comment: [React router](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview) You need to map your components to a route so whenever you hit a link, the matched component will execute